# How do I start indexing with dmoz?

Tags: java, database, indexing, search-engine, web-crawler

Open Directory Project like *[dmoz](http://dmoz.org)* , very finely categorizes each and every website. Though said to be the starting point for any crawler project. I am confused. I just cannot figure, how to use *dmoz* as a tool in indexing ?

What do I scan in each directory that has many sub directories and so on ? I understand scanning a webpage like [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) but I cannot figure this with dmoz.

*Note - I want to make my own search engine for the learning purpose.I have tried to emulate dmoz as a part of it.*

Comment: You can use the content to seed your crawler.

Comment: @qqilihq Can you please be more clear

Comment: DMOZ can give you the URLs (in form of the catalogued pages; optionally only for a specific category, if you want to focus on a specific topic), which you can use as a starting point for your crawler.

Comment: @qqilihq yes,it will give the urls..But what do I do of many levels of directories that needs to be crossed before ? What are sub directories meant for ? How will they help me in indexing ?

Comment: These are questions which are specific to your use case. Analyze the categories and their structure and decide what's relevant for your purpose.

Comment: You are not getting my point. How can a crawler find the ordering as presented by _dmoz_ a tool for indexing ? I have heard of crawlers crawling web pages. But it is a directory

Comment: DMOZ doesn't rank sites listed on it, so I think you cannot use it as an "indexing tool" (as you use this term). Meanwhile Google highly increase site's rank, if it's listed in DMOZ, since DMOZ is a higly trusted resource.

Comment: @qqilihq Can I have a word from you ?

Comment: @Oleg I meant the indexing, the crawler does.

Comment: As you said before, I'm not getting your point. How is a directory different from a general web page (or web site, to be precise)?

Comment: @qqilihq Directories lead us to web pages by categorizing the content. Webpage is an entity on its own, that can be linked to a web-directory.